# How to fix "AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri." error in Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, dotnet-httpclient, refresh-token

Following this procedure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

I'm trying to get a refresh token from this microsoft end point: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Using PostAsync method from **System.Net.Http.HttpClient** class from nuget (asp.net core 2.2) library, I'm able to get a response back with this error: **"AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri."**:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/LhP5kYf.png]

I tried to set some redirect url in the Azure Portal including:
`https://automation.legroupeti.com/Configurations/GetRefreshToken/
https://automation.legroupeti.com/Configurations/GetRefreshToken
https://automation.legroupeti.com/
https://automation.legroupeti.com`

The post request is the following (Using PostAsync method from **System.Net.Http.HttpClient** class from nuget (asp.net core 2.2)):
[image: https://i.imgur.com/PI4mo8Y.png]

Here are the configured redirect urls form the registred application in the Azure Portal:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/aqYDJhn.png]

I expect a valid response from the endpoint.
How do I configure the redirect_uri to be valid?

**EDIT 1**

I fixed the redirect_uri parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the authorize and token endpoints.

If you want the user to authenticate, you have to redirect the user to that URL, not send a POST request to it.
After the user returns to your app, you need to exchange the authorisation code for tokens. 
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview

If you want a token just for your app without user authentication, you need to call the token endpoint. 
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview

Comment: I'm trying to use the https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize endpoint to get an authorization code.

This is why I'm doing a post resquest at https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize. 

With the following parameters: 
client_id,
response_type,
redirect_uri,
response_mode,
client_secret,
scope and 
state.

As describe here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user, the response should be a page where the user need to consent, then it should redirect to the redirect_uri after the consent.

Comment: You can't get an authorization code with a post request. You need to redirect a user browser there.

Comment: Redirect the user instead of doing a post to the url did fix the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error and for me the issue was that I was encoding the `redirect_uri` value in the post request to the `/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint. Notice how `redirect_uri` is not encoded in this request.

```
POST /{Tenant ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: {cookie}
Content-Length: 941

client_id={Application (client) ID}
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret={secret}
&code={code}
```

I used the Postman sample provided by Microsoft to find the root cause.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token

Comment: Thanks men, it worked!!. Also note that your url and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#token-request show us a encoded url in the example :S

Comment: Thank you! This was the same problem I was having!

Comment: Oh man... thanks microsoft
![ms](https://i.imgflip.com/4vtr07.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

From the screenshot, it appears that the URLEncoding is incorrect. The '/' character in the path should be encoded to %2F, while your code has %2. (After '.com' and before 'Configurations'.)

Also, have you considered the Authorization Provider from the SDK?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider

Comment: Ok, it was a good catch, I did fixed the value, see EDIT 1. Sadly, it did not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem:

> AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri.

I tried few URL variants (with encoding, without, etc.) in Chrome, but was getting different exceptions about a wrong URL. Then I used the Safari browser and voila, I got a response code.

In the final result, I just copied the URL from the documentation, pasted `tenant` and `client_id` values from the registered application into the `return_url` parameter, and instead of the `/myapp/` prefix I pasted `%3A8080`, where `%3A` it's the `:` symbol. The `redirect_utl` param has to be the same as URL in the registered application.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without URL encoding. Maybe because the parameter is in the body and it's not a query parameter.

Postman example:
[image: postman example]